# how to update model EF from sql server database in mvc4 Application by vS2012 Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a database first MVC4 application of VS2012 Express but after change sqldatabase i got this error:

> {"An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the
>   inner exception for details."}

please help me anyone.

Comment: Your question makes a little sense. Can you explain a little more and show us some of your efforts. And also post the `inner exception`.

Comment: Well, what is the `error` exactly?